# sem_open returns 0 under linux

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore

This sounds like a trivial question, but I couldn't easily find a solution around.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sem_t * my_semaphore = sem_open("./my_semaphore", O_CREAT, 0755, 1);
    cout<<my_semaphore<<endl;
}
```

This prints out 0: the semaphore wasn't created. What am I doing wrong? I tested this code on an OSX environment and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Use `perror` to figure out what the error is. (And drop that `using namespace std;` before you hurt yourself.)

Comment: Ok. It says "No such file or directory.". Isn't the O_CREAT flag supposed to make it create the semaphore...?

Comment: The name must be "/my_semaphore" and not "./my_semaphore"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux manpage for [`sem_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) says (emphasis added):

> `ENOENT` The `O_CREAT` flag was not specified in oflag and no semaphore
>                 with this name exists; or, `O_CREAT` was specified, **but name
>                 wasn't well formed**.

The [`sem_overview`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) says this about semaphore names:

> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form
>   `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
>   `NAME_MAX-4` (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial
>   slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are
>    slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem starting from GLIBC version 2.34.

`sem_open` returned always `NULL` and error code was set to `ENOENT` (2).

The problem was, that on my Linux system there was no `/dev/shm` directory. Starting from GLIBC version 2.34, this folder is a requirement to use shared semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_open.html

> If name begins with the slash character, then processes calling sem_open() with the same value of name shall refer to the same semaphore object, as long as that name has not been removed. If name does not begin with the slash character, the effect is implementation-defined. The interpretation of slash characters other than the leading slash character in name is implementation-defined.

Implementors of the `sem_open()` function can define what happens if the name doesn't start with a /.  It appears that linux doesn't allow such names.